# Custom ImageViews missing when running app in API 7 and below

Tags: android, api, imageview

I have a bit of a curious problem. My Android application works on my phone (Android version 2.3.5, API 9), on some of my emulators (Android version >= 2.2, API >= 8, tested on API 8, 13, 15) and not on other of my emulators (Android version < 2.2, API < 8, tested on API 4, 7). The app doesn't chrash on the emulators with API < 8, but some of my custom ImageViews go missing on the screen. Otherwise everything works as it should.

I have used the latest version of the tool *lint* to identify if I use any methods not supported by API < 8, but the only thing I have identified is that I use one method that requires API 4, no error messages about API when setting android:minSdkVersion=4, android:targetSdkVersion=4 and build target to 4.

I have also looked [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html) since the error seems to occur between API 7 and 8 somewhere, but could not find anything. I have also checked all the methods in my custom ImageView against the developer docs in order to see if any of the methods needed API > 7.

Does anyone have any other suggestions to what the problem might be?

**Edit:**

Here is my main xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/gameLayoutID"
  >  

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/groundMenuID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    class="com.foo.bar.someClass"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/topLeftMenuID"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/TopLeftRightMenu_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopMenu_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    class="com.foo.bar.someClass"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/topRightMenuID"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/TopLeftRightMenu_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopMenu_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    class="com.foo.bar.someClass"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/leftMenuID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/groundMenuID"
    android:layout_below="@id/topLeftMenuID"
    class="com.foo.bar.someClass"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/rightMenuID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/groundMenuID"
    android:layout_below="@id/topRightMenuID"
    class="com.foo.bar.someClass"/> 

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/topMenuID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/TopMenu_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/topLeftMenuID"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/topRightMenuID"
    class="com.foo.bar.someClass"/>

<com.foo.bar.CustomImageViewLayout
    android:id="@+id/wheelMenuID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftMenuID"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightMenuID"
    android:layout_below="@id/topMenuID"
    android:layout_above="@id/groundMenuID"/> 

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/figurePassageID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/figurePassage_height"
    android:layout_above="@id/groundMenuID"
    class="com.foo.bar.someClass"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragments are inflated through standard Fragment classes' onCreateView methods and they work fine no matter the API. As for the custom ImageView class ... it is a lot of code and I am not sure if I want to paste it in the open (it is kinda my main intellectual property). I am pretty sure the error is not in there, but I will verify it again. If not I will try to paste some code.

Comment: Probably if you post some code we might be able to help you :) (xml views where the problem occurs and your custom imageview).

Comment: @YuviDroid: I have updated with my xml file. The fragments work fine, I guess the error is likely to be in the CustomImageViewLayout (which is an extended RelativeLayout) class or in the custom ImageView itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all your usage of `match_parent` to `fill_parent`.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. Unfortunately I have already made those changes to no effect.

Edit: this suggestion is due to the change of fill_parent to match_parent from API 7 to 8. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html)